# Orthogonal projection of a point to a plane given its equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the projection of $(2, 3, 8)$ on the normal to the plane $2x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 4$.

I know this question is basically asking me to find the coordinate of the perpendicular from the point to the plane. I've seen several examples but I don't quite understand why signed distance and unit vector is used, as well as how to identify if the vector is in opposite direction.

Could someone please walk me through the method of solving this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unit normal vector to the plane is $\frac 1 3 (2,2,1)$. Orthogonal projection of $v$ on  a unit vector $w$ is $ \langle v, w \rangle w$. So the projection in this case is $(4,4,2)$.

Comment: Thanks but would you mind elaborating <v, w>w. How do I compute this mathematical formula?

Comment: The general formula for the orthogonal projection of $v$ on the space spanned by orthonormal vectors $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ is $\sum \langle v, w_i \rangle w_i$.

Comment: See for example the heading 'Finding the projection with an inner product' in the following:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra) @HuiSanChiam

Comment: I was wondering how do I find the vector v in this case, if i'm only given a point (2, 3, 8) ?

Comment: $v=(2,3,8)$. That is the vector for which we are asked to find the projection. @HuiSanChiam

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Thanks a ton!! @Kavi